# Convert String to list in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query like:

`SELECT col1,col2 from table1 where col1 in (:var);`

and this :var has a value like "'1234', '5678'" which is a string consisting of single quotes and commas in it. I want to convert this string to a type which can be given as input to the SQL 'in' operator, something like this:

`SELECT col1, col2 from table1 where col1 in (STRING_SPLIT(:var));`

Comment: You don't; that isn't how `STRING_SPLIT` works. You need to `JOIN` to the split value or use `IN` against a subquery (that uses `STRING_SPLIT`). Alternatively, switch to a table type parameter, and then you don't need to use `STRING_SPLIT` at all.

Comment: `DECLARE @var AS NVARCHAR(100) = '''1234'', ''5678''';
SELECT col1, col2 
FROM table1 
WHERE col1 IN (SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(value)) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@var, ','))`

Comment: How does this ref helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914576/t-sql-split-string

Comment: @NIKUNJPATEL Thanks a ton, you saved me !!!!. Please add your solution as an answer.

Comment: @Sufi Answer added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code as solution to achieve desired result in SQL server query.

```
DECLARE @var AS NVARCHAR(100) = '''1234'', ''5678'''; 
SELECT col1, col2  FROM table1  WHERE col1 IN (SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(value)) FROM STRING_SPLIT(@var, ','))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `STRING_SPLIT` to expand a delimited literal string into *multiple* delimited literal strings. `STRING_SPLIT('abc,def',',')` doesn't result in `'abc','def'`, it results in a data set of 2 rows, containing the values `'abc'` and `'def'`.

If you want to pass a delimited string, you need to either `JOIN`/`CROSS APPLY` to `STRING_SPLIT` or use a subquery:

```sql
SELECT T1.Col1,
       T1.Col2
FROM dbo.table1 T1
     JOIN STRING_SPLIT(@YourVariable,',') SS ON T1.Col1 = SS.Value;

SELECT T1.Col1,
       T1.Col2
FROM dbo.table1 T1
WHERE T1.Col1 IN (SELECT SS.Value
                  FROM STRING_SPLIT(@YourVariable,',') SS);
```

You may, however, find even better performance with an indexed temporary table, *if* you are dealing with large data sets:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #temp (Value varchar(30) PRIMARY KEY); --Use an appropriate data type. I assume unique values in the delimited string

INSERT INTO #temp (Value)
SELECT SS.Value
FROM STRING_SPLIT(@YourVariable,',') SS;

SELECT T1.Col1,
       T1.Col2
FROM dbo.table1 T1
     JOIN #Temp T ON T1.Col1 = T.Value;
```

Finally, which may be better again, you could use a table type parameter. Then you would, like the above, just `JOIN` to that or use an `EXISTS`.